# Python - Pandas - Plotting Count of Column by Group - Graphing Each Group Over Time

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

Sorry if the title is horribly vague, its hard to express the issue in a few words.

I have recently read 'Python For Data Analysis' and have been trying to bring it over to real world examples.  I did have to replace some information in my Dataframe/images to generics (e.g. app1, app2).  Otherwise the data and results are all real.

I munged a log file, to give me a CSV with Error Level, Date of the Error, and What App generated the Error.  I am trying to create a visualization, showing time across the X Axis, with 4 ( one per app) seperate line graphs indicating the count of errors from that app, at the specified time.  What I am getting, is a line graph showing the count of Errors for ALL apps as 1 value, across a set of time.
[image: counts = df['APP'].groupby(df['DATE']).count()]
[image: counts = df['APP'].groupby([df['DATE'], df['APP']]).count()]

Here is my code, from iPython

```
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.read_csv('clean.txt')
counts = df['APP'].groupby([df['DATE'], df['APP']]).count()
counts.plot(rot=45)
```

Here is my DataFrame

```
    LEVEL                      DATE   APP
0   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.916   app1
1   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.916   app1
2   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.916   app1
3   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.874   app2
4   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.908   app3
5   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.908   app3
6   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.908   app3
7   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.908   app3
8   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.908   app3
9   ERROR   2014-07-29 12:35:55.975   app4
```

Here is my DataFrame, when Grouped.

```
DATE                      APP 
 2014-07-29 12:35:56.028   app1    6
 2014-07-29 12:35:56.029   app1    3
 2014-07-29 12:35:56.030   app1    3
 2014-07-29 12:35:56.031   app1    6
 2014-07-29 12:35:56.032   app1    3
...
 2014-07-30 13:08:57.769   app2    1
                           app1    6
                           app4    2
 2014-07-30 13:08:57.770   app2    5
```

Where am I going wrong?  I have all the information I need in the DataFrame, so I know I must just be missing something in regards to manipulating it correctly before attempting to plot it.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: You might try creating a pivot table from the grouped dataframe. Pandas generally wants different columns for each line to just automatically do what I think you're looking to do.    http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.0/generated/pandas.tools.pivot.pivot_table.html

Comment: I read that doc, and this one http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html , and I am still not seeing how to obtain what I am looking for.  Would you be able to provide a bit more information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {'level' : ['ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR', 'ERROR'], 
 'DATE' : ['2014-07-29 12:35:55.916', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.916', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.916', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.874', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.908', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.908', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.908', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.908', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.908', '2014-07-29 12:35:55.975'],
 'APP' : ['app1', 'app1', 'app1', 'app2', 'app3', 'app3', 'app3', 'app3', 'app3', 'app4']}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Then, create a pivot table:

```
df.pivot_table(values='level', index='DATE', columns='APP', aggfunc=len).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

I plotted it as a bar chart, since each app only has 1 occurrence in the example data, and thus there's no line to plot. Just change 'bar' to 'line'.

Of note, if you have thousands of different times, and want to view the number of errors for the entire day, you will need to do a little more processing. The resample function is really good for this.